# How to change jquery UIslider value With input Radio

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on Jquery UIslider and as you can see [here: http://jsfiddle.net/9PsY7/25/](http://jsfiddle.net/9PsY7/25/)  Slider is working fine but what i want to use it to change the slider value with Radio input elements.

1. When Radio `input"0"` is selected the slider should work normally as it is working now.
2. When Radio `input"10"` is selected by user then value of Slider should show it value+10 immediately.

I am new in Jquery please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

There an method of slider called `value` which you use like this:

```
$('#my_slider').slider('value', '100'); // 100 for example
```

You could easily bind that to an event:

```
$('#my_radios').change(function(){
   var t = $(this);
   if ( t.attr('checked') ){ // only selected one
       $('#my_slider').slider('value', t.val());
   }
});
```

Hope this helps...